# Aren't sensitivity analysis and recall analysis same in binary classification?

Tags: precision-recall

I have received a comment from a reviewer where he has advised me to provide a sensitivity analysis in my manuscript. My problem was, broadly, a binary classification problem. I had already given a recall vs precision analysis in the manuscript.

As far as I know, recall and sensitivity are the same in binary classification. Did the reviewer miss the point? Or do I need to provide a separate sensitivity analysis? If I need to give a sensitivity analysis, how should I do it?

Comment: Maybe they're referring to the sensitivity with respect to your training/test data. Did you do a cross-validation?

Comment: I kept a separate validation set and has shown the analysis on the validation set.

Comment: Can't say for sure if this was what the reviewer referred to, but cross-validation could make a stronger case for your work.

Comment: Ok, I think they missed it as it was a long manuscript. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Statistically speaking, a sensitivity analysis is not designed to measure the quality of your model with respect to your input parameters. It is designed to assess the importance of each parameter with respect to your quantity of interest.

One of the most famous method is called *Sobol'* indices. Let say you have 2 inputs `x1, x2`. If `S_x1=0.8` and `S_x2=0.2`, it means that the variance of the quantity of interest is at 80% due to `x1` versus 20% for `x2` (considering that there are no interactions effects).

In python you have plenty of options to do this (*SALib*, *Batman*, *openTURNS*) and in R there is the package *sensitivity*.